# Zeroed out joints values

Tags: python, maya

I have a few joints in my scene and I would need to zeroed out its channel values as I parent those joints into different mesh (which are in different places within the scene)

I know that I can manually type out `cmds.setAttr(joint01.translateX, '0')` so on and forth for the other translation as well as the rotational attributes.
Are there any other ways in which I can compile it within a line or two (something like freeze transform though it doesn't works on joints) instead of writing out 6 lines?

```
ls = cmds.ls(type="joint")
for item in ls:
    cmds.setAttr(item + ".translateX",0)
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

EDIT : I am creating solo joints for the creation of ribbon spine, thus would like to know if there are any other shorter method that I can write instead of writing out 3 or more sentences of `setAttr`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want [`cmds.makeIdentity`](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2010help/CommandsPython/makeIdentity.html).  You can specify which attributes to zero out.

Howver, remember that this does different things to geometry and to joints. It changes the vertex positions of the geometry to reflect the moves, rotations and scales before zeroing the transform values; with joints, it moves rotations into the JointOrient and repositions child joints.

Comment: Hi, correct me if I am wrong but whenever I have used Freeze Transformation on a single joint, it has only zeroed out the Rotation values. I also did tried using the makeIdentity command and it is not working as expected since the menu? command didn't work

Comment: You can't zero the translation on a single joint: if the joint is the root of the hierarchy, it will keep its original translation. If it's a child joint, its translate will change to compensate for scales and rotations on joints above it. When you freeze geometry, the actual vertices are moved to preserve the visual appearance; that's not possible with joints.  If you really need 0-0-0 values in a joint you'll need to interpose a new joint or transform above it to hide the underlying transforms

Comment: Yes I understand what you are trying to imply. Also pardon me as I realized that I am making it unclear in my post. In actual fact, I am not trying to zero-ed out the 'parented' or child joints as I am creating solo joints, in the case for ribbon spine

Comment: If the joints are soloed the only way to zero them out for real would be with dummy transforms above them.  You can 'zero' geometry by shifting the geo before resetting the transform; you can't do that for joints which are just transforms with an the extra JointOrient / RotateOrient.  Setting tx, ty and tz to zero as in the example you posted will move the joints to origin

Comment: I see... Hmm, I think I will stick back to the `setAttr` command then as I am going to 'snap' the joints onto each individual hairFollicle. Thanks again!

Comment: You can also use constraints to do the snapping: just create parentConstraints or pointConstraints with the -mo option turned off, then delete them right away for cheap alignment